# Docker image size and layer caching best practices

Tags: docker, meteor, containers

Might be a noob question here. I'm playing around with Docker builds for my Meteor project and noticed that in [this](https://github.com/abernix/meteord) repo for a popular base image, the author suggests using the `devbuild` during development and the `onbuild` for production.

**devbuild**

```
ONBUILD RUN bash $METEORD_DIR/lib/install_meteor.sh  # install dependencies
ONBUILD COPY ./ /app
ONBUILD RUN bash $METEORD_DIR/lib/build_app.sh  # build the app
```

vs  **onbuild**

```
ONBUILD COPY ./ /app
ONBUILD RUN bash $METEORD_DIR/lib/install_meteor.sh  # install dependencies
ONBUILD RUN bash $METEORD_DIR/lib/build_app.sh  # build the app
```

I assume the former uses Docker's layer caching capability to speed up the build, and he warns that using the `devbuild` for the final build would result in a much larger image than necessary since it contains the full meteor installation.

This seems to contradict what I've read in guides like [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#sample-dockerfile) from the Docker Quickstart, and [this one](https://stackabuse.com/deploying-a-node-js-app-to-a-digitalocean-droplet-with-docker/), that recommend installing dependencies first so they can be cached.

Is there a difference between the situation presented in the meteor guide vs the node guides, and what's the best way to build these dependencies in production?